# kendo UI to develop website + apps

Tags: kendo-ui

I am a rusty ASP.net developer who last worked on .Net 2.0 some 4 years ago! However, I'm ambitious and hope to spend the free time I get while raising my son on developing a website with supporting apps. I've used and liked telerik before but havent touched Linq, Jquery, xcode etc. How good is Kendo UI and how easy will it be to learn to use it? Are webservices  the way to go?
Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you for your answers and sorry for causing grief, but I haven't had the time to investigate Kendo UI yet. I was wondering if I can create web and mobile apps talking to the same core web services.. and if kendo might help me build these presentation layers that talk to the same business logic.

Thanks for clarifying mustafa and Lars, turns out jQuery and kendo are related and things come together if you read the first line of their documentation! Kendo means I don't have to learn jQuery. So my life will be easier (I hope).

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/introduction

Comment: I think you can just write your experiences about Kendo-UI and also he didn't ask linq, jquery , xcode. He said "I didn't use this technologies".

Comment: @MustafaP let me rephrase: how much you know about LINQ or Xcode won't make any difference wrt how difficult learning Kendo UI will be for you or whether it's a good product. I think you both need to review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - whether or not Kendo UI is good or easy to learn is not a question that can be answered objectively

Comment: my honest advice is to read the introductory documentation for the tools and platforms you want to use first; then you'll be able to ask more targeted questions; if you want to build mobile apps with HTML, then I suppose the answer is yes - you can build your UI with Kendo UI (and there's no fundamental difference when accessing web services from a mobile browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m working for 5 months on a project in which Kendo Ui is used. There are lots of documents, demos and examples, so learning Kendo Ui is too easy. Also coding is very simple and I like its themes.

I noticed only one bad way because of thread structure, sometimes events and read functions don't work correctly and stable . I had to use setTimeOut() for queuing functions and events.

I didn't use any WebService with Kendo, so I can't say anything about it. But I can certanly suggest Kendo Ui

Comment: I agree Kendo UI is really great. I've run into a couple nuances, for instance, add to use Request.Form[] for MultiSelect because it wouldn't bind to the model. But other than that its awesome. I can't comment on the Javascript version of it, I've only used the Razor Enginer